# Are there any species a Vulcan can't mind-meld with?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, spock

We see in Spock that Vulcans seem to have the ability to mind-meld with a lot of species - humans, other Vulcans, lava silicon-based monsters.  Is there actually any species a Vulcan *cannot* perform a mind-meld with (i.e. is there any reference to a Vulcan not being able to perform a mind-meld with an individual *because* it was a certain species?)  I grant that the obvious answer would be a machine/computer, but I would prefer an answer of an actual species (the Borg really are a pseudo-race and are a collection of species rather than a species in themselves for the purposes of this question anyway).

Comment: Lt. Com. Data??

Comment: @SachinShekhar I do state in my question that I'm looking for *biological* species rather than mechanized forms (androids included).  I would expect, however, that a mind-meld with a machine wouldn't be possible because of the language barrier (AFAIK computers don't think like we do)

Comment: Anyone know about the Ferengi? Betazoids can't read them...

Comment: It is never explicitly stated in the show, but since a mind meld seems to involve physically touching your target, I guess it would be hard for a Vulcan to meld with a Tholian.

Comment: The Hutts? Jabba the Hutt once said that mind tricks don't work on them..

Comment: @Einer Meld melds can work through an environmental suit (The Motion Picture), so they might be able to do one with a Tholian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only species observed to be resistant to [mind melds](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vulcan_mind_meld) that Memory-Alpha lists are the Cardassians, however, this is attributed to their mental training and discipline. We only see one Vulcan use it on one Cardassian (Dukat), so its effectiveness may vary person to person (initiator and target).

Comment: There are also a number of species that the Vulcan never *try* to mind meld with who might be immune - Ferrengi come to mind.  Both as a species that might be immune, and as a species the Vulcans would never mind meld with.

Comment: @Zibbobz Yea, there are certainly species that may be immune, as you say. But it is never established for sure. As for a species that *the* Vulcans would never meld with, I think that that is very variable. We see Spock meld with some weird aliens (the horta for example), and Tuvok melded with Seven while she was suffering multiple personalities, so there was no telling what he might have encountered there. I think that *what* a Vulcan will meld with is largely up to personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Spock was unable to maintain his meld with a Kelvan. Any species with a super-intellect (Organians, Q, Douwd, Cytherian, etc.) would undoubtedly be impossible for a Vulcan to meld with. It'd be like an ant trying to understand the thoughts of a human. Plus, changelings cannot be read by Betazoids, and I'm guessing that Vulcans wouldn't be able to meld with them either, as their "brain" isn't something that can be readily accessed.