# Could telepaths read a changeling's mind?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Has anyone ever heard of an instance where somebody from a race of telepaths (for example, Betazeds) tried to read the thoughts of a changeling posing as a solid and what the results were? Could a changeling somehow hide its identity without giving itself away?

Comment: Worth noting that the Founders attack and occupy the Betazed homeworld during the war. They don't destroy the planet or genocide the people though...

Comment: *"a changeling posing as a solid"* As opposed to what state they are usually in (e.g. 'solid').  I could do that..

Comment: “They don't destroy the planet or genocide the people though” — a missed opportunity if ever there was one.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite- wow SOMEone has a real problem with Betazeds.

Answer (score 7):

We know from [DS9: Fascination](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Season_3/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_-_456_-_Fascination.txt) that a powerful telepath (Lwaxana Troi) is unable to read our resident changeling, Odo:

> **LWAXANA :** *What is it, Odo?* (off his reaction) *I may not be able to read your emotions, but I can read your expression.  Something's
>   wrong.*

However, we see in [DS9 : Things Past](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/3_Deep_Space_Nine/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_Season_5/Star_Trek_-_Deep_Space_Nine_-_506_-_Things_Past.txt) that changelings (as a species) actually have quite a substantial telepathic ability:

> **ODO :** (off PADD) *The plasma storm that hit the runabout activated the enzymes and initiated a telepathic response.*
>
> **BASHIR :** *Your mind reached out to find other changelings to form the Link, but it could only find Dax, Sisko and Garak.*

I think it's reasonable to assume that a more experienced changeling would be able to control that telepathic ability to perfectly mimic a human (or alien) mind, at least sufficiently to fool a Betazoid scan.

Comment: There's also the difference of a changeling's mind to consider. The differences in Ferengi brains make it impossible for Betazeds to read them, and changelings are far more different to Betazeds than Ferengi are.

Comment: Late to the party here, but it would be interesting to know whether a Vulcan could -- after all, Spock was able to mind meld with a Horta :-).  For that matter, can a Vulcan read a Ferengi?

Comment: @Basya - Worth [asking as its own question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). "**Can a Vulcan mind-meld with a Ferengi?"**. Possibly a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58456/are-there-any-species-a-vulcan-cant-mind-meld-with

Comment: Thank you.  That possible duplicate doesn't quite satisfy me, but I don't know whether there is a better answer; it may never have been addressed.  OK, I'll bite: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/277111/59154

Comment: @Basya - Be aware that your question might end up getting closed as a duplicate of the first one. Either way it's brought attention to your specific question about Ferengi :-)

Comment: @Valorum - thanks.  I know it might be.  I mentioned in the question why I am asking it separately; I refer directly to the question you referred to.  I