# Can a Vulcan mind-meld with a changeling?

Tags: star-trek, telepathy

We have seen Spock mind meld or have telepathic contact with several aliens, including at least one extremely physiologically different (Horta).

The answer to [Are there any species a Vulcan can't mind-meld with?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58456/are-there-any-species-a-vulcan-cant-mind-meld-with) does not include changelings/Founders in the list of species with which a Vulcan can not mind meld, but the source is Memory Alpha.

[Could telepaths read a changeling's mind?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79771/59154) has an answer which brings evidence that Betazoids can not read changelings' minds, but no information has surfaced about Vulcans -- an we know from the Horta that Vulcans are not limited to 'similar' species.

Is there any canon source where a Vulcan actually attempts a mind meld with a changeling (and fails or succeeds), or which mentions that it is possible or impossible?

*If there is no canon source*, then I would be interested in answers from books.

Comment: Presumably, the Horta has a physical brain (or thinking organ) that Spock was able to access. Obviously, Changelings are something totally different. However, since Spock was able to read the probe Nomad, I don't think any species, save for those that are exceedingly powerful (Q, Nagilum, GoF, etc.), can be for sure included in the list of "un-meldable" without good canon evidence or implication.

Comment: @HamSandwich - canon evidence, one way or the other, is kind of what I'm hoping for.  Doesn't appear to be forthcoming though!